# Delete not needed data from memory

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I have a function which loads 8 GB of data and then return 6 MB of data (a list).
But then i launch multiprocess based functions and the whole 8 GB gets passed to all processes where as i need only the 6 MB returned by function.Due to this , the memory usage is 8*process_count . How can i remove unneeded data worth 8 GB.

Pseudo Code:

```
def fun():
    uses another function to load a big json file and get keys from it.     
 something like this:
 return [k for k,v in ext function returning a big dictionary created from big json file]

def main():
    list_ll = copy.deepcopy(fun()) # done to remove reference to fun
    gc.collect()
    launch multiprocess functions each of which takes a part of list.
    All 8 GB data is being copied.Memory usage too high.
```

Comment: What's with the copying at all... why not just `list_li = fun()` ? What exactly does `fun` do... are there any references left somewhere else that could be referencing the large data.... do you actually need the whole 8gb in RAM to focus on the 6mb?

Comment: @JonClements i did copy etc...so that gc.collect would remove the function data....but that didnt work.....there are no other references other that fun.......yes i need 8 gb data to get to 6 mb list

Comment: As long as `fun` is returning the 6mb and you're doing `whatever = func()` that's fine... `deepcopy.copy` is just complicating things and achieving nothing. Without seeing what `fun` is doing, what `list_li` is (are you sure that doesn't contain references to the 8gb)) or how you're doing the multiprocessing - I doubt anyone is going to be able to help.

Comment: @JonClements added more details.Please check